# Passthrough TeX input

Tags: tex-core, conversion

I need to convert a document that was written in `TeX` to some other format.

The other format supports a `TeX` style mathmode, so I would like to turn every mathmode formula into verbatim.

I tried turning each formula into a verbatim environment, but this does not work, as an `end` statement has to be visible at the same time as an `begin` statement is encountered.

How can I achieve something like that?

`pandoc` et al are not an option. There is too much customization in the TeX processor used for those documents to work.

A small example:

I would like the input

```
$$ \left\{ \min_{3, 5} \right\} $$
```

To be output as exactly that, without having to modify the `.tex` files.

More explanation of what I'm doing here:

I have a huge style file, which defines a domain specific language for documentation, and a custom (somewhat conforming) latex interpreter that is used to output HTML code. I want to transfer the current LaTeX documents into a new document format. For that I'm modifying the style-files to adapt some constructs to the new format. The mathmode constructs are especially troubling and always get modified in ways I cannot really comprehend. Thus, I'm asking if there is a standard way to turn every latex formula into its verbatim equivalent.

Comment: Can you be more explicit - perhaps a short MWE, showing what the input `TeX` looks like and what the output should be, in its new format? A script (`python` or `perl` or `awk`) may be your best bet.

Comment: Does this really have something to do with TeX? You wouldn't use TeX for the conversion, would you?

Comment: @egreg As it is, I do. The tex files are rather complex and actually building a tex parser/interpreter is a ton more work than hacking the style files to do what I want. I'm grateful for every other suggestion.

Comment: I don't understand. You have explained to us that you want the mathmode stuff to not be modified. Fine. But unless we know how the other stuff _is_ being modified, it isn't clear what mathmode needs protecting _from_.

Comment: I don't understand. `:(`

Comment: @egreg @Seamus I did my best to explain the situation further. If this is not enough related to `TeX`, I'll remove the question.

Comment: What should actually happen with the math material? Turning it to verbatim would mean the TeX code of the formulas would be **typeset** into the document, which isn't really converting it to anything. Would you like to write the math stuff to a file?

Comment: @StephanLehmke Writing it to a file is already in place. Now I need to write it to a file without triggering any TeX escaping, e.g. `\{` should be output as `\{`.

Comment: @pmr Your "LaTeX interpreter" is not TeX based, I presume. Or is it?

Comment: @egreg No, it is an entire custom hack. But supports it reasonably well.

Comment: To get more help, your MWE should show a complete input document (not just the math mode stuff) and all the output documents you hope to see.

Comment: it's not clear to me how this stuff would be written in your original document.  if i wanted <verbatim> stuff to go to a file, i would use the verbatimwrite env from moreverb (or some similar verbatim pkg), but that prevents your document from showing the stuff in the first place.  so i guess i'm yet another person wanting clarification of your process.  sigh...